# Large Merchant Services Bulk Dat Exchange Service. Which Service Class do I use?

Tags: api, ebay-api

I was hoping you could help me.

This question concerns the Large Merchant Services eBay API. I am writing the program in C#, using Visual Studio.

I am trying to use make a ActiveInventoryReport using the BulkDataExchangeService API call of StartDownloadJob.

I have made successful calls using the Trading API by defining a "eBayAPIInterfaceService service = new eBayAPIInterfaceService();" class as the service, and then using that class to send the request. For example:

```
 GetSellingManagerInventoryRequestType request = new GetSellingManagerInventoryRequestType();
        request.ErrorLanguage = errorLanguage;
        request.Version = "915";
        request.WarningLevel = WarningLevelCodeType.High;
        request.Pagination = paginatorType;

        GetSellingManagerInventoryResponseType response = service.GetSellingManagerInventory(request);
```

Below is the code I'm trying to write to make the StartDownloadJob call. However, I'm finding that the "eBayAPIInterfaceService" class doesn't contain a definition of StartDownloadJobResponse and therefore I can't use the "service.StartDownloadJobResponse(request);" statement.

I know that "eBayAPIInterfaceService" probably isn't the class I need.

My question is: what class am I suppose to be using? I cannot find any documentation that tells me!

```
`string endpoint = "https://webservices.ebay.com/BulkDataExchangeService";
        string callName = "StartDownJob";
        string siteId = "0";
```

`` string appId = "MyId";     // use your app ID
    string devId = "MyId";     // use your dev ID
    string certId = "MyId";   // use your cert ID

    string version = "467";

    // Build the request URL
    string requestURL = endpoint
    + "?callname=" + callName
    + "&siteid=" + siteId
    + "&appid=" + appId
    + "&version=" + version
    + "&routing=default";
    // Create the service
       eBayAPIInterfaceService service = new eBayAPIInterfaceService();

    // Assign the request URL to the service locator.
    service.Url = requestURL;

    // Set credentials
    service.RequesterCredentials = new CustomSecurityHeaderType();
    service.RequesterCredentials.eBayAuthToken = "[MyTokenHere]";    // use your token
    service.RequesterCredentials.Credentials = new UserIdPasswordType();
    service.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.AppId = appId;
    service.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.DevId = devId;
    service.RequesterCredentials.Credentials.AuthCert = certId;

    // Make the call to GeteBayOfficialTime
    StartDownloadJobRequest request = new StartDownloadJobRequest();

    StartDownloadJobResponse response = service.StartDownloadJobResponse(request);` ``

Any help would be appreciated!